# Styling DT to float left of DD

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a definition list such that each `dt` floats to the left of its corresponding `dd` elements. I have used:

```
dt {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 6.5em;
}
```

which works as far as it goes. It nicely handles multiple `dd` elements per `dt` and `dd` text that is long enough to span multiple lines.

However, I'd really like to be able to cope with multiple `dt` elements per `dd` (which is valid HTML) and `dt` elements that are taller than the corresponding `dd` elements (due to length of text causing the lines to wrap). At this point the styling falls apart and subsequent `dd` elements get out of line with their `dt`.

I have tried various things such as floating the `dd` as well, which breaks alignment of multiple `dd` elements. Adding `dd + dd { clear: both; }` which almost works but now long `dd` text sits under its `dt` (not to mention older browsers not respecting the rule).

Has anyone managed to do this? I really don't want to give up and use a table but maybe it's appropriate.

My test markup is here: http://pastebin.com/nmAQ5Xdm

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find a way to do it. You might have to use `div` and `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this when you don't mind constraining the width of the `dl` element:

```
dl {
    max-width: 30em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
dt, dd {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
dt {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
}
dd {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    width: 22.5em;
}
```

It's not perfect as the styling breaks if the viewport is too narrow for the `dl`.

Comment: +1 thanks.  How do you make the dd a little bit wider, maybe up to 50em?

Comment: The `max-width` for the `dl` needs to be the sum of the widths of `dt` and `dd` plus the `margin-left` of the `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Set a width on the dt and float it left.  Then leave the dd as `display: block` (default) and give it a margin-left of the same amount.  Now the dd will wrap at the same width as the dt.  The floating of your dt will clear the `block` dd automatically.  You can adjust the spacing between the dt/dd pair by adjusting the `margin-bottom` of the dd.

If you might have empty dds, then you can add `clear: both` and `margin-bottom` to your dt too so that it will end up in the right place without dd content to put it there.

```
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 8em;
}
dd {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle OP's "`dt` elements that are taller than the corresponding `dd`..."